# Does google first search as per the user given order of keywords in search bar?

Tags: google, google-search, keywords, seo

Does google first search as per  the user given order of keywords  in search bar?

For example :

I typed word1 word2 word3 word4 word5 in google search bar.

Now my question is does google first search titles matching the order.

Two case:

1. If it DOES so and unable to search for any webpage with that keyword order, does it skip to broad search?
2. If it DOES NOT, and there is page with that same order keyword typed, would it fetch that and display first, asumming that only my webpage have the order in which the user asked for in Google.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Google will return the most relevant searches for the search terms given. (Unless quotes are used) it does not mean that all of the words will be found on those pages or in the order they are provided. The order of the words is a ranking factor as is the presence of the word in page. But they are factors like incoming links are a factor and it is very possible that other factors outweigh them. As a result pages with the words in a different order or lacking a keyword *may* outrank another page that has all of the keywords or has them in the proper order.